# Adding next and prev button to tabbed content slider

Tags: tabs, navigation, jssor

I am using the jssor tabbed content slider and the only navigation are the tabs at the top. How can I add next and prev buttons?

**HTML**

```
 <div u="slides" class="vertical-slide slide-3-text" style="top:0">
            <div>
                <div class="panel">Slide 1 content, place any html here.</div>
                <div u="thumb">REACH</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="panel">Slide 2 content, place any html here.</div>
                <div u="thumb">INSPIRE</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="panel">Slide 3 content, place any html here.</div>
                <div u="thumb">ENROLL</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="panel">Slide 4 content, place any html here.</div>
                <div u="thumb">CULTURE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unzip jssor.slider.fullpack.zip and find any arrow skin 'skin\arrow-**.source.html' that you like.

Add $ArrowNavigatorOptions as follows,

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                $ChanceToShow: 2
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>
```

And then place arrow navigator skin html code in 'slider1_container'.

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- open 'skin\arrow-...source.html', copy and paste arrow navigator skin here -->
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
</div>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html